# Assembly, NASM; how is the information in 32 bit registers divided among sub registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, endianness, cpu-registers

For example, EAX is divided among AX and AH and AL. So if I do this:

```
push eax
mov eax, [szString] ;; where szString holds the string 'test'
```

Then how will 'test' string be divided among the three sub registers? For example, what does AX hold?
Could some please explain why this is in terms of bits? For example how many bits is the string 'test' and how is it partitioned?

Comment: `mov eax, szString` will move the address of _szString_ into _EAX_ not the actual characters themselves when using _NASM_

Comment: ok. what if i do mov [eax], szString

Comment: I thought lea moved the address and mov moved the actual value?

Comment: I think you mean `mov eax,[szString]` in which case, AL will have the first t, AH will have e, AX will have et.  It's been likely 15-18 years since I've touched assembler, but that's what I remember anyhow.

Comment: Robert is correct. that's what i meant.

Comment: It's not like it would have taken more time to test it than ask it here...

Comment: Could some please explain why this is in terms of bits? For example how many bits is the string 'test' and how is it partitioned?

Comment: x86 is little endian so it loads starting with the least significant byte. Strings are laid out sequentially as expected. You can put together the rest yourself.

Comment: With _NASM_ `mov eax, szString` and `lea eax, [szString]` do the same thing. If you use `mov eax, [szString]` which moves the 4 byte contents starting at pointer szString then the characters will be placed into _EAX_ in reverse order. The first character will be in the bottom 8bits of _EAX_ (_AL_) and the top 8 bits of _EAX_ will contain the 4th character

Comment: Thank you. The reverse order part really cleared up a confusion i had!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AL will have the first t, AH will have e, AX will have et (te depending on how you consider the lower character and higher character). It's been likely 15-18 years since I've touched assembler, but that's what I remember anyhow.

szString will look like this in memory:

```
t    e    s    t
0x74 0x65 0x73 0x74
```

mov eax,[szString]

```
will have:
AL - 0x74
AH - 0x65
AX - 0x6574
EAX - 0x74736574
```

Primitive ASCII art:

```
[74][65][73][74]
[-----EAX------]
[--AX--]
[AL][AH]
```

Comment: I think a proper answer would involve a discussion or reference to endianness (x86 being little endian)

Comment: what will have 's' then?

Comment: The lower part of EAX that is above AX, or bits 16-23.  AX is the least significant 16 bits of EAX (bits 0-15).

Comment: Thank you. this was very useful in my understanding!

Comment: Finally clicks considering each char is at most 8 bits long and the stack grows towards lower addresses, but here it is pushed in reverse.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but I also noticed that your ASCII characters are off a bit. `t` = 0x74 and `s` = 0x73

Comment: @harris and Robert: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has lots of good links.  IIRC, there's a register diagram in there, showing how ax is a subset of eax, and so on.